# Is there a relation between eigenvector and amplitude for a beaded string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string, oscillators

I have a string fixed at both end with 5 beads.
At $$t=0$$ $$v_p=0$$ where $p$ is the index for each bead and their initial displacement are $$(3,0,\sqrt{3},2,2)$$ I have to find the amplitude for the second and third mode (order by frequency), using the formula for the eigenvector of a mode. Which is $$<n| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_N}}(\sin(\frac{n\pi p}{N+1}), \sin(\frac{n\pi p}{N+1}),...)$$
Where $N$ is the number of beads, $p$ the index of the bead and $n$ the mode.

Is there a relation between the eigenvector for a mode and the amplitude?

It is possible to order the eigenvector by frequencies?